# Encryption with RSA (modulus/exponent) : too much data for RSA block

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I have a `modulus key` and an `exponent key`, I create an `RSA public key` to encrypt a `data`, but I get this exception

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block
```

**Here are the details:**

the Modulus value:

```
B390F7412F2554387597814A25BC11BFFD95DB2D1456F1B66CDF52BCC1D20C7FF24F3CCE7B2D66E143213F64247454782A377C79C74477A28AF6C317BE68BC6E8FF001D375F9363B5A7161C2DFBC2ED0850697A54421552C6288996AC61AF5A9F7DE218ABBC75A145F891266615EB81D11A22B7260F7608083B373BA4BC0756B
size: 256
```

the Exponent value:

```
010001
```

the Data to be encrypted:

```
1A0498EA0DF19B45043DA4688AE3A7B3D592D61CC0EBB82FB100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
size: 256
```

and here is the code:

```
public static String encryptData(String data, BigInteger modulus, BigInteger exponent) throws Exception {
    RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    PublicKey pub = factory.generatePublic(spec);
    Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pub);

    byte[] cipherText = rsa.doFinal(data.getBytes()); // ERROR HERE
    return Hex.toString(cipherText);
}
```

Here is the public key generated

```
30819F300D06092A864886F70D010101050003818D0030818902818100B390F7412F2554387597814A25BC11BFFD95DB2D1456F1B66CDF52BCC1D20C7FF24F3CCE7B2D66E143213F64247454782A377C79C74477A28AF6C317BE68BC6E8FF001D375F9363B5A7161C2DFBC2ED0850697A54421552C6288996AC61AF5A9F7DE218ABBC75A145F891266615EB81D11A22B7260F7608083B373BA4BC0756B0203010001
size: 342
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand. What is the public key of size 342 supposed to be? The RSA public key consists of the public exponent (0x10001) and the modulus (size: 256).

Comment: That's the public key generate `PublicKey`

Comment: am I missing something here ?

Comment: Basically, the error says it all. You can't encrypt something bigger or equal than the modulus. RSA is usually not used in a block mode (java doesn't support it; I don't know about BouncyCastle). Use hybrid encryption with AES if you want to encrypt bigger data.

Comment: `getInstance` will apply some default padding scheme (E.g. PKCS1) this will mean you can only encrypt data upto a size equivalent of the key size *less* the padding bytes, E.g. -11 for PKCS1

Comment: @AlexK. so the data should be of a size of 128 - 11 = 117 ?

Comment: If that's the padding that's used it would be 256 - 11;see [RSA maximum bytes to encrypt, comparison to AES in terms of security?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/rsa-maximum-bytes-to-encrypt-comparison-to-aes-in-terms-of-security)

Comment: @ElJazouli Since PKCS#1v1.5 encryption padding is insecure, you need to use OAEP which has bigger padding (about 41 bytes).

Comment: Thank you all, it actually was a stupid error. check my answer for details

Comment: Encrypting with RSA without padding is not secure. You must use padding if you want the ciphertext to be secure. Cf. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/why-is-padding-used-for-rsa-encryption-given-that-it-is-not-a-block-cipher.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to use public key (asymmetric) encryption with large documents is to create a random, single-use passphrase. The passphrase is used with a password-based encryption (symmetric) algorithm (e.g., AES-256). Use AES to encrypt the document and then use the public key to encrypt the passphrase.

Generally speaking, symmetric encryption algorithms tend to be a couple of orders of magnitude faster than asymmetric encryption algorithms. So, not only does RSA not lend itself to directly encrypt large documents, but it also would take much more computation to do the encryption.

As an aside I will mention that encryption is hard to get right. I would strongly urge you to use a standard library in a standard way to ensure a secure implementation.

Comment: Thanks!! but the issue was in this line `byte[] cipherText = rsa.doFinal(data.getBytes());`, check my answer

Comment: AES expects a (uniformly) random, fixed length key, not a passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

the error is just stupid:

```
byte[] cipherText = rsa.doFinal(data.getBytes()); // ERROR HERE
```

I encrypt `data.getBytes()`, but actually I first need to decode `data` from its hex representation and only then encrypt it.

Comment: Really? This is it? I would thought that it still doesn't work because the modulus is also hex encoded and therefore exactly the same size.